# dotnet.exe test command file reference fails MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core, mstest, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API / .NET Core application running that builds  and executes tests locally and on other developer machines.  It also runs fine in Docker (we build/test application prior to building docker).  We are trying to automate our builds using Visual Studio Team Services and the solution builds fine, it is when it executes the tests on VSTS there is an issue.  The application is loading assemblies at run time that it reads from the configuration file, thus when the application tries to load the assembly, it throws an exception (below) saying it cannot be found.  The values in the configuration file are relative paths.  Anything obvious that I am missing

```
System.Exception with message "Unable to load assembly or type. A: R:\agent\_work\4\s\Support\<assemblyname>, T: <TypeName>. Error: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

When the application runs from Visual Studio, it runs fine.  When I run the below command, I can recreate the error we get on VSTS.

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test <Project Directory>/project.json --configuration release
```

Any help determining the proper way to reference these files would be much appreciated.

- Developer Environment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- Testing Framework: mstest
- "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.4-preview"
- "dotnet-test-mstest":   "1.1.1-preview"

UPDATE 2/22/17
I am still unable to run the build from VSTS.  When I run the command "dotnet.exe test" from a command line that is sourced at the folder of the Test Project, I am able to run the projects.

When I change the path to exclude the ".", I still have the error locally and on VSTS.  I have updated the project to reflect this.  Below are my build definition:

1. .NET Core - Restore

   - Project: **/project.json
2. .NET Core - Build

   - Project: **/project.json
3. .NET Core - Test

   - Project: test/HostConsoleAppTest/project.json (I also used the relative path)

VSTS Errors:

> 2017-02-22T17:32:01.3057263Z Unable to load assembly or type. A: D:\a\1\s\Support\ImplAssembly.dll, T: ImplAssembly.TestReference. Error: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
>   Running the reference with no dot
>
> 2017-02-22T17:32:01.3057263Z Getting Configuration
>
> 2017-02-22T17:32:01.3057263Z Creating implementation via assembly
>
> 2017-02-22T17:32:01.3057263Z Unable to load assembly or type. A: D:\Support\ImplAssembly.dll, T: ImplAssembly.TestReference. Error: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)

Git Repo has been updated

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. (Step: 1. Create a .Net Core Web API, 2. add "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.4-preview" and "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.1.1-preview" 3. Add "testRunner": "mstest" to project.json.) You can try to run the test through Visual Studio Test step with project.json and /UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx arguments. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/01/announcing-mstest-v2-framework-support-for-net-core-1-0-rtm/ Can you share a simple project that can produce that issue on the OneDrive. Also, please provide the detail build log.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I have added the sample project to git:
https://github.com/JShewchuk/TestCommandReferenceTest

The command output is in the readme.md file.  Also note, that this error is the same that we are seeing on VSTS.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue at my side and you can use "Command Line" task as a workaround for now:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @starain-MSFT Can you post what you did because that did not appear to work for me and broke the test when running from Visual Studio.

Original Error
System.Exception: Unable to load assembly or type. A: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio 14.0\Support\ImplAssembly.dll, T: ImplAssembly.TestReference. Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

New Error:
System.Exception: Unable to load assembly or type. A: C:\Support\ImplAssembly.dll, T: ImplAssembly.TestReference. Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @JShewchuk I just downloaded the sample you provided and upload it to my VSTS project and then create a build definition. I selected the "ASP.NET Core (PREVIEW)" template.

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental that I am overlooking as I have not had this issue on-prem

Comment: @JShewchuk I just reproduced your issue at my side but haven't figure out the root cause yet. For now, you can use command line task as a workaround. I added a screenshot in my answer for your reference.